# Which steps I have to do to get this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I don't know what to do to derive the right side from the left side: $$\frac{B}{1+r} = B - \frac{r B}{1+r}.$$

Comment: Instead, derive the left side from the right side (with a least common denominator), then work backwards.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Write the numerator of the left hand side as $B(1+r-r)$ and use the fact that $$\frac{a+c}{d}=\frac{a}{d}+\frac{c}{d}$$  for $d\neq 0.$

---

**Added**:
Observe that $\,\,$ $B=B(1+r-r)=B(1+r)-rB.$
So $$
\begin{align*}\frac{B}{1+r}&=\frac{B(1+r)-rB}{1+r}\\
&= \frac{B(1+r)}{1+r}-\frac{rB}{1+r}\\
&= B-\frac{rB}{1+r}.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Could you please show the whole transformation?

Comment: @Georg: I have added to my answer.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** $\ $ It's simply $\rm\displaystyle\ 1\ =\ \frac{1+r}{1+r}\ =\ \frac{1}{1+r}\ +\ \frac{r}{1+r}\ $ rearranged, then scaled by $\rm\:B\:.$